# Backup and restore with VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, restore, snapshot

A VirtualBox's newbie here. I created a snapshot of a VM by using this command line:

```
VBoxManage snapshot VMName take BackupName
```

Then I used this to check:

```
VBoxManage showvminfo VMName
```

and I saw a snapshot was created with the name BackupName. I didn't find an "actual" snapshot BackupName, I found a file filename.sav in SnapShots folder.

My intention was to create a snapshot of this VM, copy it to another host machine and restore it there. Since I couldn't find the "snapshot" BackupName, so I copied sav file to new host and used this command:

```
VBoxManage adoptsate filename.sav
```

But it didn't work. Can anyone help me how to copy that "snapshot" and restore it in a new host. Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to go to VirtualBox Manager's `File` menu and use `Export Appliance`. A snapshot is only a differences file realtive to another file on the same machine, not a complete image of a VM that may be transported around.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell for your explanation. Unfortunately, the host carries the VM which I want to backup does not have VirtualBox UI, that's why I have to use plain command line there. Any other solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, get a list of the Virtual Machines installed on your host at the command line:

```
vboxmanage list vms
```

**Sample Output**

```
"UbuntuVM" {77743eca-e338-471c-b824-60c5c5c22b6f}
"Windows XP SP3" {3818afc4-189d-4441-8f35-07284c930a4b}
"Windows XP SP3 Clone" {79b40316-225a-43a1-9ddf-22a51c280d4e}
```

Find the one you want to export to a different host, and export to a file called `Ubuntu.ova` like this:

```
vboxmanage export UbuntuVM -o Ubuntu.ova
```

Comment: Before using export, make sure that the vm is powered off: `vboxmanage controlvm <vm-name> poweroff`

Comment: @daemon12 First, you should shutdown a running system, not powering it off. Second, your answer is not "covering" the case of a running VM that shouldn't be stoppend (this is why the author is trying snapshots.